# What is the purpose of Observable.of operator in RXJS library?

Tags: rxjs

```
data = [{'info':'success'},{'info':'fail'}];
public getResults(page: Page,data:any[]): Observable<PagedData<CorporateEmployee>> {
    return Observable.of(data).map(data => this.getPagedData(page,data));
}
```

In the above code what is the purpose of the `Observable.of` operator?

Comment: The purpose is what [the documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md) says it is. Also, this has nothing to do with Angular, other than the fact that rxjs is commonly used in Angular. Nor does it have anything to do with TypeScript.

Comment: You could also take a look at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of.

Comment: `of` is not an operator, by the way. The term "operator" refers to things that are applied to observable instances, such as `map`.

Comment: Oh! Ok, @torazaburo. I am new Angular and RXJS. I consider the 'of' is the operator of Observable before your information. Now i clear. Thanks for your  explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we should use RxJs Of() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889210/why-we-should-use-rxjs-of-function)

Answer (score 6):

It wraps the array object into the `Observable` stream for later `Observable` processing. Your function returns an `Observable`, the `map` function is the Observable function (also array has this), and if you want to work with Observable stream, you need to convert your array into the Observable stream and use its functions.

Comment: Thank you torazaburo and @Suren Srapyan.