# Why we should use RxJs of() function?

Tags: javascript, angular, service, rxjs, angular2-services

in service section of angular.io tutorial for angular2 I hit a method named of.for example :

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return of(HEROES);
}
```

or in below sample:

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  // Todo: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
  this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
  return of(HEROES.find(hero => hero.id === id));
}
```

in angular.io Just explained

> used RxJS of() to return an Observable of mock heroes
> (Observable<Hero[]>).

and It was not explained why we should use `of` operator and exactly what does it do and what are its benefits?

Comment: I would say it's used for simplicity. Of is a pretty basic component of Observable, in that all it does is emit what you give it to emit, and then moves on to the next line. Nothing complicated, it's asynchronous, and it gives beginners a good grasp of how Observables work on a basic level.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The reason why they're using `of()` is because it's very easy to use it instead of a real HTTP call.

In a real application you would implement `getHeroes()` like this for example:

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(`/heroes`);
}
```

But since you just want to use a mocked response without creating any real backend you can use `of()` to return a fake response:

```
const HEROES = [{...}, {...}];

getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return of(HEROES);
}
```

The rest of your application is going to work the same because `of()` is an Observable and you can later subscribe or chain operators to it just like you were using `this.http.get(...)`.

The only thing that `of()` does is that it emits its parameters as single emissions immediately on subscription and then sends the `complete` notification.

Comment: if you want to simulate request you can add some delay as follows `of(HEROES).pipe(delay(5000));` - the result will be emitted 5s after subscription. This `pipe-delay` is also handy if you want to simulate some delay for real this.http... request - which is useful sometimes for some debugging scenarios

Answer (score 14):

Observable.of() is useful for maintaining the Observable data type before implementing an asynchronous interaction (for example, an http request to an API).

As [Brandon Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4962764/brandon-miller) suggests, Observable.of() returns an Observable which immediately emits whatever values are supplied to of() as parameters, then completes.

This is better than returning static values, as it allows you to write subscribers that can handle the Observable type (which works both synchronously and asynchronously), even before implementing your async process.

```
//this function works synchronously AND asynchronously
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> { 
  return Observable.of(HEROES)
  //-OR-
  return this.http.get('my.api.com/heroes')
  .map(res => res.json());
}

//it can be subscribed to in both cases
getHeroes().subscribe(heroes => {
  console.log(heroes); // '[hero1,hero2,hero3...]'
}

//DON'T DO THIS
getHeroesBad(): Array<Hero> {
  return HEROES                             //Works synchronously
  //-OR-
  return this.http.get('my.api.com/heroes') //TypeError, requires refactor
}
```

Comment: `of` also works synchronously unless you specify you different `Scheduler`

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, I assume that the `HEROES` variable is an array of objects, in which every object corresponds to interface `Hero` (or is the instance of class `Hero`). When we call this function somewhere in the code, it will act like this:

```
heroService.getHeroes()
  .subscribe((heroes: Hero[]) => {
    console.log(heroes) 
    // will output array of heroes: [{...}, {...}, ...]
  })
```

It means, that when we use `Observable`'s `of` creation method with array as argument, on subscription it will emit the whole array, not its' elements one-by-one

In the second example, when we subscribe to `Observable`, that was returned from `getHero()` method, it emits only one hero, whose id corresponds to given id.

Basically, when you create `Observable` with `of` method and supply arguments to it, on subscription it emits these arguments one-by-one

[Here's a good reference](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html)

Comment: I think he's asking why use Of() in the first place if only one object is being returned in both examples.