# Call parent component function from child when child components are in router outlet Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to update some data in parent component by calling a function in it after an event has occurred in the child component.
Here my child components are in router outlet of parent

parentComponent.html:-

```
<div class="row">
     Parent component
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Parentcomponent.ts:-

```
fetchRequestsStatus(role, user) {
if (this.userRole) {
  this.dashboardService.getStatusCount(role, user).subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res)
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

}

Now on a button click in the child, I need to call function `fetchRequestsStatus(role, user)` by passing a parameter from the child. I have seen @input @ output decorators for sharing data but here my child component is inside the router.

How can I proceed with this?

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication/36018798#36018798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're thinking something like

`<router-outlet (onButtonClick)="fetchRequestsStatus($events)"></router-outlet>`

it's invalid as the child component you're thinking is a child component is actually a sibling component at runtime.

I am guessing this is your app component. So, you can have a subject in the `app.service` which can be an observer for the child and an observable for the parent.

Comment: i have created a shared service but how can i get a function results as observable?

private messagesource = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
currentmessage = this.messagesource.asObservable();

that currentmessage must include a result from a httprequest

Comment: Use `of` from `rxjs`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889210/why-we-should-use-rxjs-of-function)

Comment: iam using real backned apllication, not returning fake data

Comment: Haha, the answer posted over there doesn't just solve for fake data. Are you trying to communicate an HTTP response from the service to the parent?

Comment: Your change message then needs to be this way `changeMessage(r,u) { this.getStatusCount(r,u).subscribe(res => this.messageSource.next(res));}`

Comment: yes

i need to call parent http request and update parent ui by hitting a button in child component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195264/discussion-between-ameer-pappay-and-aakash-verma).

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution would be to create a shared service between the parent and child component, service that holds an Subject used by parent and child component.

Refer to this answer for code sample:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989983/5620535

Make sure you use the new `providedIn: 'root'` angular feature to make sure the service is only instantiated once. (singleton)